# Is it possible to import MKV file with chapters in PowerDirector?

Tags: video, video-editing, matroska

I'm trying to figure out how to import an MKV file in Cyberlink PowerDirector is that possible? is it possible to work out with the chapters like deleting some of them, or changing start/end time? If PowerDirector can't handle it, I would like suggestions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple solutions I've found:

1)  tsMuxeR: Output Blu-ray disk

2)  ImgBurn (Options: UDF 2.50) or Nero Burning Rom

---

1)  AVS Video Converter: To Blu-ray (2-channel audio (6 ch. unplayable))

```
    a.  Menu: Chapters: Auto Set Chapters: As in Input File(s)
```

2)  ImgBurn (Options: UDF 2.50) or Nero Burning Rom

---

1)  DVDFab: Creator

2)  ImgBurn (Options: UDF 2.50) or Nero Burning Rom

---

1)  TMPGEnc Video Master Works (DTS not supported)

```
    a.  Auto import keyframe info

    b.  Cut-edit: Export keyframe list to same folder as output

    c.  Format: Blu-ray standard, BDMV, 1080x1920

    d.  Change Audio to 5.1 ch
```

2)  TMPGEnc Authoring Works

```
    a.  Allow/Find import of keyframe file
```